# Transformar CURL em classe

Tags: php, classes, libcurl

Gostaria de transformar meu código `curl` que está estrutural e coloca-lo em uma `classe`, mas estou sem lógica, *NÃO QUERO NADA PRONTO*, apenas quero exemplos, veja minha classe.

```
<?php

$cookie = [];

$username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'));
$password = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));

$index_url = 'https://twitter.com';

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
      CURLOPT_REFERER         => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => ['Cookie:' . http_build_query($cookie, '', ';') . ';'],
      CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
          if (preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?)=(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
            $cookie[$matches[1]] = urldecode($matches[2]);
          }
        }
        return strlen($header);
      }
    ]
);    
$access = curl_exec($token);

preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $access, $matches);

$authenticity_token = $matches[1];

$session_post = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$session_url = 'https://twitter.com/sessions';

curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $session_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $session_post,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Cookie: '. http_build_query($cookie, '', ';').';',
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1
  ]

);
$auth = curl_exec($token);

if (isset($cookie['auth_token']))
{
  $twid = filter_var($cookie['twid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  Cookies::set('login_token', $cookie['ct0']);
  Cookies::set('kdt', $cookie['kdt']);
  Cookies::set('user_id', $twid);
  Cookies::set('auth_token', $cookie['auth_token']);
  Cookies::set('username', $username);

  $_SESSION[SITE_TITLE . '_session'] = $username;

  echo json_encode(array(
    "status"      => "success",
    "message"     => "Autenticação bem sucedida, estamos te redirecionando.",
  ));
}
else
{
  echo json_encode(
    array(
      "status" => "error",
      'message'=> "Não foi possível autenticar com o Twitter.",
    ));
}
```

Estou sem lógica para transformar isso em Orientação a objetos, queria colocar esse código exposto há cima dentro de uma classe, para que eu possa reutilizar futuramente em outros processos, mas estou sem lógica pra isso, um amigo programador me disse no Facebook: Recomendo criar uma classe pra cada `CURL` estou usando `MVC` e criei um helper veja:

```
<?php

class Curl {

}
```

Contém apenas isso. Estou procurando exemplos na internet, mas não encontro

[tentei isto como exemplo](https://github.com/shuber/curl/blob/master/lib/curl.php)

Porém comigo não funcionou, nem erros mostra, no `wamp` não criou log de erros. Eu queria um exemplo básico. o Resto eu dava meus pulos.

**EDITADO**

Acho que isto é o suficiente realmente estou sem lógica, preciso de ajuda :(

```
<?php

class Curl {

    public function setUsername($username) {

    }

    public function setPassword($password) {

    }

    public function curlInit($init) {

    }

    public function curlClose($close) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisará primeiro analisar a situação e avaliar quais serão os atributos e métodos que precisará na classe, assim como você faz com qualquer outra classe. Um processo que talvez facilite é fazer algo semelhante ao que ocorre com a biblioteca MySQLi, onde existe sempre um método para cada função estrutural.

Comment: Nunca mexi com mysqli_* mas vou ver o que posso fazer. confio nos seus comentários pois vc ja me ajudou muito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Se eu seguir o mesmo exemplo do PDO serve também ? eu já sei os métodos que vou usar. vai ficar uma bagunça mas depois eu concerto deixo clean.